# How to pull value of element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to toggle between Celsius and Fahrenheit. I have a working button and it will make the calculation but I cannot seem to grab the value the weather API generates from the element. My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not used to working with API's. The API generates the temperature in Celsius and places it in "weather-temperature". Here is  the HTML:

```
<h4>Current Temperature:</h4><h1 class="weather-temperature farenheit celcius" id="temp"></h1>
    <button id="toggle">Toggle F&deg;/C&deg;</button>
    </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var temp = ; // How do I get the value of #temp to be stored in var temp? 
   var celsius = temp;
   var fahr = (1.8 * temp + 32);
   var switch_ = new Boolean(false);

   $("#toggle").on("click", function () {
       switch_ = !switch_;
       var temp = switch_ == true ? celsius + " °C" : fahr + " °F";
       $("#temp").text(temp);
   });
```

Really stuck on this one. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `new Boolean(false)` is always `true`, because it's an instance of `Boolean`. you might use `false` directly.

Comment: do you have an API problem, or just the wrong starting unit?

Comment: The API works great and stores the temperature in Celsius in h1 #temp. I need to somehow get that number and store it in my var temp so that I can convert to Fahrenheit. I'm really stuck. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a weather API and get the value of temperature in celcius, set that value in your `temp` variable as you see that your `temp` variable is not initialized which is used in `celsius` and `fahr` variable. Doing so will work for you.

```js
var temp = 10; // set the temperature fom API
var celsius = temp;
var fahr = (1.8 * temp + 32);
var switch_ = new Boolean(false);

$("#toggle").on("click", function () {
   switch_ = !switch_;
   var temp = switch_ == true ? celsius + " °C" : fahr + " °F";
   $("#temp").text(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Current Temperature:</h4>
<h1 class="weather-temperature farenheit celcius" id="temp"></h1>
<button id="toggle">Toggle F&deg;/C&deg;</button>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, set the temperature from the API. The API calculates the temperature in Celsius but I do not know how to grab that data from #temp and store it in the var temp.